# Axios try/catch with async await is returning promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to get some data from an API but I'm recieving promises instead of data

```
    const fetchCoordinatesFromAdress = async (adress: any) => {
        let response = {}
        try {
            response = await MapBoxAPIService.getCoordinatesFromAdress(adress)
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e)
        }
        return response.data
    }
```

if I console log response.data I get the data but I want to return the data and then it just returns the promise

Comment: `async` functions **always** return promises. To access the promise's eventual value, either call `.then` on the promise, or `await` it. eg, `const data = await fetchCoordinatesFromAddress('foo');`

Comment: Could you show the `getCoordinatesFromAdress` function in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Call it with `await` or `.then()`
Example:

```js
const data = await fetchCoordinatesFromAdress(address);
```

or

```js
fetchCoordinatesFromAdress(address).then((data) => ...)
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise